# Building calendar in PHP

Tags: php, calendar, switch-statement

I'm practising PHP and I have been told to write a calendar.

So, I have done a function to know how many days every month have (the names are in catalan, hope it is not a problem to understand what I'm trying to say).

```
$months = array("Gener" => "01", "Febrer" => "02", "Març" => "03", "Abril" => "04", "Maig"=> "05", "Juny" => "06", "Juliol" => "07", "Agost" => "08", "Setembre" => "09", "Octubre" => "10", "Novembre" => "11", "Decembre" => "12");

function month_length($months)
      {
    $leap_year = date("L");

    switch ($months) { 
        case "Gener":      return 31;       
        case "Febrer":   
            if ($leap_year === 1) {
                return 29;
            } else {
                return 28;
            }
        case "Març":       return 31;
        case "Abril":      return 30;
        case "Maig":       return 31;
        case "Juny":       return 30;
        case "Juliol":     return 31;
        case "Agost":      return 31;
        case "Setembre":   return 30;
        case "Octubre":    return 31;
        case "Novembre":   return 30;
        case "Decembre":   return 31;
        default:           return "numero incorrecte";
    }    
 }
```

Then, I guess I have to make another function to loop through the returned value, one per one, but I have no idea how... How can I take the returned value of each case and work with it if it make sense?

Comment: PHP has a wealth of existing functions to make this kind of thing real simple. Try this for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Comment: I know I know, I have been looking around and if seen dateChooser and datePicker..... but because the purpose of this is to practise, I have to do it manually (as I struggle a lot when I have to write functions....)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to take the output of the month_length function, and loop through each day of the month.

```
$days = month_length($months)

for ($i = $days; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    // $i, will increase by 1 as we loop through each day
}
```

Comment: aha, it make sense! let me try!

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if this solved your problem.